Is there a restrictive principle within phenomenology (especially when discussing Aspect theory)?
So I would like to start by saying my apologies to the terms and terminologies that I will be using when asking my questions. I am new to phenomenology and thus do not really know the terms but instead I am going to be using relational (math) concepts to discuss my question. I hope it makes sense.
My  question basically emerges from an intuition I had, my intuition goes something as follows, "Every object can be understood through the senses but this understanding is limited because we don't experience the object as a whole partially because of abstractions that are inherently present when sensing the object. Take for example, a ball you can see the ball and you would get the information of what it looks like through sight but this is only one property of the ball you are receiving thus all the other properties are not being perceived and we partially know there are other properties because of the other senses but they are limited from being sensed or understood through the eyes thus at all times one is always getting an abstraction of that object through its properties but never the full object itself (as the full object is constituted of all its properties basically)" After which, I did a quick ChatGPT search and found that this was basically like Edmund Husserl's Aspect theory so now the barrage of questions goes as follows if one can engage all five senses and interact with the object does that mean that person has fully interacted with the object or are there still properties of that object that are still not being perceived i.e., is there another extra abstraction that is required until all the properties of the object are perceived and how can we know this i.e., if humans had more sense perceptions would we possibly get more property information from the object through even more abstractions or would that extra sense basically not obtain any information at all because the object doesn't have any more property to share, all the senses have been engaged?
What I am basically saying is that does every objects property match up to our senses i.e., is there a one-to-one correspondence between properties of objects and our senses where through complete integration of the senses we can fully perceive an object or are there more properties that exceed the senses?
My second question that is sort of a follow up, but also a sort of principle is that in whatever scenario the properties of the object are either in a one-to-one correspondence with the sense or in a many-to-one correspondence there is never a situation where in the correspondence ratio there are fewer properties of the object to the senses, but I am basically not sure if this is right? Could there be any counterexamples or is my intuition wrong?
One more question is that I have a strong intuition and feeling that Husserl's Aspect theory is ultimately right that objects basically have a many-to-one correspondence with our senses, but I am trying to see if there are any philosophical ideas/concepts that adhere to a one-to-one correspondence or is this not an actual conceivable option i.e., are there no concepts within philosophy that adhere to this idea?
Speculation: Does empiricism kind of claim that we can fully know or understand an object through empirical evidence i.e., by exhausting all physical properties of an object we can arrive at a full conception or understanding of an object?

In phenomenology a thing is defined in terms of essence and existence.  The essence is quiddity, whatness, idea, concept.  Existence is the actuality of the notional thing ascertained through the senses.
If you make a plain bronze cubic paperweight then you know exactly what the object is because you created it. Its colour: bronze, shape: cubic, material: bronze, function: weighing down papers. If it turns out that due to alloy admixtures the paperweight is magnetic this means it can also be the base for a magnetic desk sculpture, which might call for a rethink as to what the object is for you, since it can be both a paperweight and a sculpture base.  But in its role as a paperweight its magnetism is irrelevant.
OP: "Every object can be understood through the senses but this understanding is limited because we don't experience the object as a whole partially because of abstractions that are inherently present when sensing the object."
The object, let's say the paperweight, is fully defined even it its magnetic properties are unknown.  On the other hand, as an object of physics its essence will necessarily be incomplete because we don't know everything about matter.
Trying to approach objects as objects of physics is always going to be incomplete, as is trying to grasp the thing-in-itself.

The thing-in-itself is nonsense. If I think all the "relations," all
the "qualities" all the "activities" of a thing, away, the thing
itself does not remain: for "thingness" was only invented fancifully
by us to meet certain logical needs—that is to say, for the purposes
of definition and comprehension (in order to correlate that multitude
of relations, qualities, and activities). – Nietzsche, WtP 558

If someone else gives you a mysterious object but doesn't tell you that it is say, a gourd, then you have only sense data to go on. Essence: 'mystery object', existence: confirmed.

Descartes knows very well that entities do not proximally show them­
selves in their real Being. What is 'proximally' given is this waxen
Thing which is coloured, flavoured, hard, and cold in definite ways,
and which gives off its own special sound when struck. But this is not
of any import­ance ontologically, nor, in general, is anything which
is given through the senses. ... The senses do not enable us to
cognize any entity in its Being; they merely serve to announce the
ways in which 'external' Things within-the-world are useful or harmful
for human creatures encumbered with bodies. ... they tell us nothing
about entities in their Being. – Heidegger, B&T
96-7

The Being of the gourd exists between the farmer who grew it and the plant beheld, therefore primarily involving the incomprehensible Being of the farmer. He gives it to you as a mystery gift.

Ultimately, of course, the "thing-in-itself" also disappears: for
at bottom it is the conception of a "subject-in-itself." But we have
seen that the subject is an imaginary thing. The antithesis
"thing-in-itself" and "appearance" is untenable; but in this way the
concept "appearance" also disappears. – Nietzsche, WtP
552


(1) The human eye cannot perceive ultraviolet light. The ear cannot perceive very high tones. We (probably?) lack a direct sense for electromagnetic fields. So, not every possible aspect or attribute of objects can be (directly) sensed with human senses. Are scientific instruments (like a microscope or telescope) simple extensions of our senses? (See: Constructive Empiricism)
(2) The same object (in the same circumstances) may be perceived as having different colors by different observers. Does this mean color is not a property? Perhaps it's not an "intrinsic" property of objects? If so, does any object have any "intrinsic properties"? (Perhaps "not intrinsic" simply means that the perception is easier to differentiate from the cause of the perception? Or perhaps only "having spatial extension" should be considered as "intrinsic"? If so, then everyday talk of properties seems to lose most sense.)
A 'property' (whatever it is) is always an observed property, observed not just in a unique, private observation, but in a series of repeated, shared observations. This implies that any 'property' is an effect somehow associated with some object. What sense does it then make to attribute properties to the objects themselves as if there was nothing "in between" as it were, no mediation by a particular mode of perception, a particular class of observers? Do we ever know objects as such or is "object" perhaps something more like an ideal?
Even if we leave the acts of observation out of consideration: Is (for instance) "hardness" a property or is it better characterized as a relation between objects ("A mineral object A is harder than another mineral B, if A can make a scratch in B")? Whether some property is attributed directly to objects or is seen as a reflection of a relation between objects or as a relation between objects and an observer (really a group of observers sharing a common language), depends on what the observer is interested in and on the general setup of the whole observation.
